# Is it possible to declare a default associative array in Smarty?

Tags: multidimensional-array, smarty

In Smarty, I know you can declare a string:

```
{$somevar|default:'some string'}
```

or even an array:

```
{$somevar|default:array('someval')}
```

How do you/Is it possible to set an associative array as a default value? as this doesn't seem to work:

```
{$somevar|default:array('default'=>array('subkey'=>'subval'))}
```

I just tried:

```
{$somevar|default:array('key'=>'val')}
```

It's the '=>' smarty doesn't like

Answer (score 0):

I know its probably not the solution you're looking for, but you can always just use the `{php}` feature. However, I will try a few things and see if I can work the format out.

Just out of interest, why are you trying to do this in the tpl file and not in the calling PHP script?

### Edit

From takeing a read, it doesn't seem like it is possible. However, there is a "set" plugin which allows it, see [here](http://smarty.incutio.com/?page=set) (bottom example).

Comment: I'm trying to do something clever with jQuery hence in the presentation logic